# Converting IntStream into 2-dimensional array

Tags: java, java-stream

After I have flattened `int [][]` into `IntStream`. I need to "split it back" into small 2 dimensional arrays following this algorithm:

```
IntSream [1,2,3,4] -> int [][] finalArr {{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}}
```

Basically,combining two nearest elements into array. I feel that it's possible to get over using [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) again, but I can't figure out. Any suggestions?

Comment: `code`int differentSquares(int[][] matrix) {
//      if(matrix[0].length<2 || matrix[1].length<2)return 0;
        Stream<int[]> stream = Arrays.stream(matrix);
       IntStream intStream = stream.filter(i->i.length>=2).flatMapToInt(x->Arrays.stream(x));
//       intStream.forEach(System.out::println);





        return ...;

    }`code`

Comment: Does the input `IntStream` consist of a sequence of consecutive integers (such as `[1, 2, 3, 4]`), or could it also be any list of numbers (such as `[1, 4, 3, 2]`)?

Comment: Nope, they are going randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `List(list)` from `IntStream` and use following code to create 2D array of two pairs:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import  java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Stream1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3,4);

        int [][] int2DArray = IntStream.range(1, list.size())
                .mapToObj(i -> new int[] {list.get(i-1), list.get(i)})
                .toArray(int[][]:: new);

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(int2DArray));
    }
}
```

Prints output:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: The problem is that I also want to get [2 , 3] in the middle of them)

Comment: Since the question was specifically about an `IntStream`, there is no need for the `List<Integer>`. Further, there is no reason to use change the requested `int[][]` to `Integer[][]`. So you can do it as simple as `int[][] int2DArray = IntStream.range(1, 4).mapToObj(i -> new int[] { i, i+1 }) .toArray(int[][]::new);`

Comment: @Holger But that relies on having a sequential `IntStream`, which might not be the case. Agreed on no need for `Integer`, neither `List`, though.

Comment: Holger and @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: thanks for the inputs edited to int[][]

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I don’t see where this relies on a sequential stream.

Comment: @Holger Sorry, I didn't mean sequential as in "sequential vs parallel". I meant sequential in the sense that the stream is a sequence of consecutive integers. What if the stream is `[1, 3, 2]`?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner and Holger Since we needed to pair elements, I was relying on data structure with index to get previous element. If there is a better way to get previous element in streams. Please let me know.

Comment: @AnuragSharma No, unless you use an external library, such as StreamEx. If you already have the index-based data structure (i.e. an `ArrayList`), the approach given in this answer is absolutely correct IMO.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner that’s giving by the OP’s example. Otherwise, we could simply use an `int[]` array as input. If the input is an unknown `IntStream`, just calling `toArray()` first, followed by this solution might be the simplest choice.